# Expire bin log in minutes

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, binlog

In the mysql conf file `my.cnf`, I want to add expiry time for the bin-logs.
After doing a quick research on that, I got to know how to set it for days.i.e., `expire_logs_days=3`.

I want to set the expiry time for every 5 minutes. Is it possible ?
How to do that ? 
I tried `expire_logs_minutes=5`, but that didn't work.

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a way to archive your wanted behavior, but you have to implement this via a cron job or similar thing, just execute:

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Above will remove your binlog-files older than five minutes. See also the documentation: [PURGE BINARY LOGS Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/purge-binary-logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. If you need to expire it in 5 minutes, why do you need binlogs at all? You may disable it.